# Free database servers

Tags: database

Do you guys know any free database hosting servers? most of the ones I came across required a license.

I'm trying to learn about databases and connection to databases using java JDBC, so I don't really have a project going to be worth paying for a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use either PostgresQL or MySQL. Both are free (MySql does have commercial-use limitations, though).

Comment: `MS Sql-Server Express Edition` is also free with limitations.

Comment: True. I took a guess that this was a non-Windows app, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not download Oracle XE or MySQL? - even though the database is on the same machine, the concepts are still the same when it comes to connecting via JDBC and other available architectures